# Correct interpretation of conditional and marginal R squared in mixed effect models

Tags: regression, r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, r-squared

I am currently running models with both random slopes and intercepts and am curious about the correct interpretation of the marginal and conditional $R^2$. From reading into them, I understand the marginal $R^2$ is the variance explained by the fixed effects and the conditional $R^2$ is the variance explained by both random and fixed effects though I am unsure what this refers to.

Example:

```
library(lme4)
library(performance)
data(sleepstudy)

fit <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 + Days | Subject), data = sleepstudy)
performance::model_performance(fit)

AIC      |     AICc |      BIC | R2 (cond.) | R2 (marg.) |   ICC |   RMSE |  Sigma
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1755.628 | 1756.114 | 1774.786 |      0.799 |      0.279 | 0.722 | 23.438 | 25.592
```

Should the conditional R squared here be interpreted as:

1. Random effects (i.e. subject) had greater variance explained than fixed effects?
2. Variance explained by the fixed effects was considerably greater when slopes and intercepts were grouped by the levels of the random effect?

Answer (score 1):

Note that for a typical $R^2$ value, defined below:

$$
R^2=1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right)
$$

It is difficult to generalize to mixed models. Our value approximates how much total variance is attributed to nothing but a naive "mean-only" model (the bottom part of the equation) versus the variance attributed the the sum of squares from a fitted model (the top part). So this is straightforward for OLS regression given the only difference between a null model and a fitted model is what we explicitly add in as fixed.

This is obviously not helpful when you also need to determine the *explicit parts of the random factors* that you want to include in a mixed model, as using a similar equation on it's own will always include both the fixed and random terms (thus we can't see directly what the fixed effects are doing). This motivates the two coefficients you describe. **The marginal $R^2$** here is the total variance attributed strictly to your *fixed intercept and slopes*. Note here I use slightly different notation from Nakagawa and Shielzeth since they use somewhat redundant terms in their original paper for educational purposes:

$$
\frac{\sigma^2_f}{\sigma^2_f + \sigma^2_r + \sigma^2_\epsilon}
$$

Which is decomposed by the following elements:

- $\sigma^2_f$ is the variance attributed to your fixed effects.
- $\sigma^2_r$ is the variance attributed to random effects.
- $\sigma^2_\epsilon$ is your leftover error.

You can see from the proportion that it approximates, out of the total variance (the bottom part), how much can be attributed to fixed effects alone (the top part).

**The conditional $R^2$** is more general. As you note, it captures everything that is attributed to the *explicit fixed and random terms* (basically everything but the leftover residuals), which can be seen by the minor change in the numerator:

$$
\frac{\sigma^2_f + \sigma^2_r}{\sigma^2_f + \sigma^2_r + \sigma^2_\epsilon}
$$

Your assumption is correct that your random effects explain more of the attributed variance than the fixed effects. This is somewhat easy to see given the high ICC value. Im not sure what you mean by your second point exactly but I think this answer should be sufficient to answer the second point. You can comment to clarify.

##### Source

Nakagawa, S., & Schielzeth, H. (2013). A general and simple method for obtaining R 2 from generalized linear mixed-effects models. Methods in Ecology and Evolution, 4(2), 133–142. https://doi.org/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x